# Javascript-created Form sending empty values

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am creating a HTML table and I want it to be editable. so I created javascript like this:

```
<script>
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("clicker");

    var buttonclicked = function(e){
        if(e.target.textContent == "Edit")
        {         
            e.target.textContent = "Cancel";
            var id = e.target.id;
            var table = document.getElementById("tr"+id);
            var editable_elements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=false]");
            var sub = document.getElementById("sub"+id);  

            var f = document.createElement("form");
            f.setAttribute('method',"post");
            f.setAttribute('action',"edit.php");
            table.appendChild(f);

            var j = document.createElement("input");
            j.setAttribute("type", "text");
            j.setAttribute("name", "subject");
            j.setAttribute("value", sub.textContent);
            j.setAttribute("placeholder", sub.textContent);
            j.setAttribute("disabled", true);
            j.setAttribute("style", "width: 150px");
            j.textContent = sub.textContent;
            sub.innerHTML = "";
            f.appendChild(j);
            sub.appendChild(j);

            for(var k = (id*6); k < (id*6)+6; k++){
                var l = k;
                var index = k -(k*id) + 1;

                l = document.createElement("input");
                l.setAttribute('type',"number");
                l.setAttribute("style", "width: 75px");
                l.setAttribute("step", "0.01");
                if(index <= 4){
                    l.setAttribute('name',"g"+index);
                    l.setAttribute('placeholder',"G"+index);
                    l.setAttribute("value", editable_elements[k].textContent);
                }
                else if(index == 5){
                    l.setAttribute('name',"creditos");
                    l.setAttribute('placeholder',"credits");
                    l.setAttribute("value", editable_elements[k].textContent);
                }
                else if(index == 6){
                    l.setAttribute('name',"criteria");
                    l.setAttribute('placeholder',"criteria");
                    l.setAttribute("value", editable_elements[k].textContent);
                }
                editable_elements[k].innerHTML = "";
                f.appendChild(l);
                editable_elements[k].appendChild(l);}

            var s = document.createElement("button");
            s.textContent = "Save";
            s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
            s.setAttribute('value',"update");
            s.setAttribute("id", id);
            s.setAttribute("name", "action");
            var clickbutton = document.getElementById("save"+id);
            f.appendChild(s);

        }
        else //save button has been clicked
        {
            //nothing
        }
    };

    for(var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++)
    {
        buttons[j].addEventListener('click', buttonclicked);
    }
</script>
```

This creates a lot of input forms in the table cells (check the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWH18.jpg) and a submit button and try to send it to my PHP file (edit.php), all seems to work well, but when it submits to the PHP file, it submits an empty string in the place of "Subject". I dont know why. I know that bracause as soon as I press "save" button it tells me I have accessed this appologize function:

```
else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if($_POST['action'] == ["update"])
    {
        //validate submission
        if(empty($_POST["subject"]))
            apologize("You must provide what subject to change");
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean to do an array `["update"]` in `if($_POST['action'] == ["update"])`, and not a string `"update"` -> `if($_POST['action'] == "update")`?

Comment: what's going on with this line? `$_POST['action'] == ["update"]`. also have you tried to simply do like `var_dump($_POST);` on the first line in `edit.php` ??

Comment: I do mean to post an array. (All the values inside those boxes in the table). This line I put it there because I have another form where I can edit or remove things from the table. So I set the edit button with a name action and a value update, and the delete button with a name action and a value delete, so after I check if server request method == post, I check which button was pressed. If you look into my script, you will see that I create a button with a name action and a value update.

Comment: The var_dump($_POST) showed me that the array being passed is only the button:
`array (size=1)
  'action' => string 'update' (length=6)`

Which is wierd, because if I submit to the same page using the other form I get this:
`array (size=8)
  'subject' => string 'foo' (length=3)
  'g1' => string '1' (length=1)
  'g2' => string '2' (length=1)
  'g3' => string '3' (length=1)
  'g4' => string '4' (length=1)
  'creditos' => string '4' (length=1)
  'criteria' => string '4' (length=1)
  'action' => string 'update' (length=6)`

Comment: I understand why, It is because of this lines of code:`
`sub.appendChild(j);`
`editable_elements[k].appendChild(l);`
Doing that after appending to the form I was removing the inputs from the form. The problem is, if I remove this lines I cant chose where will my inputs be, and they stay like this:
http://imgur.com/PVyrl0E
Besides the table row, and not in it